# Структура проекта

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars

Пишу на node, express js и шаблонизаторе Handlebars. До этого писал на php и разносил header и footer в разные файлики. Как тоже самое можно элегантно сделать на node?

Comment: Handlebars из коробки поддерживают partials.

Comment: как этим пользоваться?  из документации не очень понятно

Answer (score 2):

А что там в [документации](https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars#goals-and-features) не понятно?

`{{> foo/bar}}` в случаи, если `bar.handlebars` лежит в `/views/partials/foo/`